# How do integrate InfoPath, SharePoint Designer 2013, and SharePoint 2013 (Foundation)?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, office-365

Please bear with me as I am very new at SharePoint (2 weeks in). We have SharePoint 2013 (Foundation), SharePoint Designer 2013, and Office 365 with InfoPath. How do I use the three together? I need to make forms with SharePoint Designer and InfoPath, but there isn't an option for InfoPath from Designer (I think because it is Foundation?). When I was watching a video I they clicked on an InfoPath icon in the ribbon, however, I don't have one. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint foundation doesn't support InfoPath forms.  If you have O365 you can use InfoPath forms there.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. We just got O365. What do you mean by "you can use InfoPath form there"? Is there any way to make forms and get them on the SharePoint site?

Comment: No, you can create and host Infopath web forms on O365.  You can use InfoPath with SharePoint foundation, but not browser based forms.  When you acccess an O365 site you will notice you have the "InfoPath" ribbon button available from there when viewing list and libraries.